# Wanting to return data to front end,not view - Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, web-services, model-view-controller, endpoint

I have set up an endpoint using Spring Framework.  My controller is being hit when I visit my URL, it grabs the JSON data that is sent and I can persist stuff to the database.  On either success or fail, I would like to return data to the front end instead of resolve the returned String as a view.  If I return a string then it trys to go to that page as I see ../WEB-INF/views/.html as where it wants to go and I get a 404.  All help is appreciated!

cc-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="
        com.classycartridges.controllers,
        com.classycartridges.mappers,
        com.classycartridges.objects,
        com.classycartridges.services" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="xxxx" />
  <property name="username" value="xxxx" />
  <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.classycartridges.objects"/>
  <!--<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/github/elizabetht/mappers/*.xml" />-->
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="com.classycartridges.mappers" />
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>cc</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/create</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

AccountController

```
package com.classycartridges.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.classycartridges.objects.Status;
import com.classycartridges.objects.UserAccount;
import com.classycartridges.services.AccountService;

@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public Status createNewUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount) {
        //System.out.println("username: " + userAccount.getUsername() + " email: " + userAccount.getEmail() + " password: " + userAccount.getPassword());
        String check = accountService.checkForExistingAccount(userAccount);
        Status status = new Status();
        //if the user email or username already exists, do not persist data
        if (("exists").equals(check)) {
            status.setStatusText("Error: Account already exists with the specified email or username.");
            return status;
        } else {
            accountService.createAccount(userAccount);
            status.setStatusText("Success, your account has been created.");
            return status;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I realize that I said that my return was a String but i also tried to make a 'Status' object to see if i needed to return an object vs. a String in case that worked, and it did not, but that is why my return has 'Status', fyi

Comment: annotate the method with `@ResponseBody`?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @ResponseBody annotation to the method

```
@ResponseBody 
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public Status createNewUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount) {
...
...
}
```